# How to access variable value without the header?

Tags: maple

If anyone can tell me how to access the individual numbers from this list without the label, that would be wonderful. Thank you. This is Maple 2020[image: suppose I want to get only '-2.9134339763' from this] software. I have included the screenshot here. For example, in this case, I would like to access -2.913439763

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
subs(values[1], x2);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.!